# Help me choose from these Differential Geometry + Riemannian Geometry texts?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

I want to choose introductory graduate differential geometry and Riemannian texts that minimally overlap with one another. I have narrowed my selection to these books. Please help me decide which ones are superfluous or whether I should read all of them. Thanks

1. Differential Geometry by Tu (1st edition, Springer, 2017)
2. Manifolds and Differential Geometry by Jeffrey Lee (1st edition, AMS, 2009)
3. Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds by John Lee (2nd edition, Springer, 2018)
4. Riemannian Geometry by Petersen (3rd edition, Springer, 2016)
5. Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis by Jost (7th edition, Springer, 2017)

Comment: My philosophy is that if you're going to spend hundreds of hours studying a subject then it's worth it to just buy all the books that look potentially helpful.

Comment: I like Petersen's book. His own research is in Riemannian geometry. If you want to learn about how PDEs are used in Riemannian geometry, I recommend Jost's book. But the other three are also excellent books.

Comment: I can barely say much more than the two other comments, but I would like to bring to your attention the wonderful book *Riemannian geometry* by S. Gallot, D. Hulin and J. Lafontaine (Springer) which is in my opinion a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that 'Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds by John Lee (2nd edition, Springer, 2018)' is the best of the bunch, and should be read first. The book is extremely clear, well explained, and covers a massive amount of material. Reading this would make Differential Geometry (Tu) and Manifolds and Differential Geometry (Jeffrey Lee) mostly redundant, but the other two cover complementary sets of material, and both are good (though I consider Petersen to be the better written of the two, and I have found a few mistakes in Jost).